# image quality in picture box

Tags: c#

Have loaded the image to picturebox in zoom mode. but the text is not clear. how to improve the quality of the image with fixed picture box size.

Comment: Start with a better quality image.

Comment: the orginal image size is large. when placde the image in picture box the text in the image are not clear (image taken from pdf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about subclass Picture Box and [interpolate yourself](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k0fsyd4e.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

set PictureBoxSizeMode to AutoSize or find a better quality image.

Comment: if i keep auto size it will alter the picture box size. i need image quality with fixed picture box size say (800, 600). how to get this...

Comment: how about StretchImage
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.pictureboxsizemode.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can subclass it, but you don't have to do all the painting yourself:

http://www.xtremedotnettalk.com/showthread.php?t=97904